# How to assign property values based on other property value of same object list

Tags: c#

**My structure**

```
public struct lumCummulativeData
{
    public byte[] lumId { get; set; }
    public float ledPwr { get; set; }
    public float batChargePwr { get; set; }
    public float batDischargePwr { get; set; }
    public float ledPwrAvg { get; set; }
    public float batChargePwrAvg { get; set; }
    public float batDischargePwrAvg { get; set; }
    public float ledPwrWh { get; set; }
    public float batChargeWh { get; set; }
    public float batDischargeWh { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string lumName { get; set; } 
}
```

**Declaring list**

```
 public static List<lumCummulativeData> cummulativeDataList
     = new List<lumCummulativeData>();
```

**I will assign value to lumId**
  `cummulativeData.lumId = lumIdByte;`*(assigned some id value)*

**Now i want to write some condition such that other property values of list object(same object) must be assigned based on lumId matching with lumId i get from network Packet.**

**Logic i tried**

```
for(int i=0; i<cummulativeDataList.Count(); i++)
{
    bool lumIdMatched = cummulativeDataList[i]
                        .lumIdCummulativeData
                        .SequenceEqual(packet.SelfID); 

    if(lumIdMatched == true)
    {
        cummulativeData.ledPwr += packet.LedPwr;
        cummulativeData.batChargePwr += packet.batchrgpwr;
        cummulativeData.batDischargePwr += packet.battdispwr;
        cummulativeData.count++;
        cummulativeDataList.Add(cummulativeData);
    }
}
```

List object is increasing instead of adding field values to existing object .which i created while assigning LumId . i want some some logic which iterate to all the existing object's LumId and add other field values when the lumId matched with the packet lumid which i get from network

Comment: What's the problem?  In what way does this code not work as expected?

Comment: list object is increasing instead of adding field values to existing object  .which i created while assigning LumId . i want some some logic which iterate to all the existing object's LumId and add other field values when the lumId matched with the packet lumid which i get from network.

Comment: And when you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  "It's not working" doesn't describe the problem.  Step through the code at runtime in your debugger.  Where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What are the relevant values when that happens?

Comment: No debug problem .i am not getting proper logic.

Comment: "I am not getting proper logic" isn't an answerable question.  If the code *is* doing what you expect it to do, then there is no problem to be solved.  If the code is *not* doing what you expect it to do, then you need to debug and find out specifically where it's failing.  You have to be able to describe the problem in order for anybody to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues. Firstly on your line

```
bool lumIdMatched = cummulativeDataList[i].lumIdCummulativeData.SequenceEqual(packet.SelfID);
```

lumIdCummulativeData is not a property of the lumCummulativeData struct, so it should probably be:

```
bool lumIdMatched = cummulativeDataList[i].lumId.SequenceEqual(packet.SelfID);
```

Secondly, you are adding a new list element to the cummulativeDataList whenever you match.  Instead you should be modifying the list element you are currently iterating.

```
for(int i=0;i<cummulativeDataList.Count();i++)
        {
           bool lumIdMatched = cummulativeDataList[i].lumId.SequenceEqual(packet.SelfID); 
            if(lumIdMatched==true)
            {
                cummulativeDataList[i].ledPwr+= packet.LedPwr;
                cummulativeDataList[i].batChargePwr += packet.batchrgpwr;
                cummulativeDataList[i].batDischargePwr += packet.battdispwr;
                cummulativeDataList[i].count++;
            }
        }
```

You could approach the problem in a different way using LINQ, which is somewhat more elegant:

```
cummulativeDataList
  .Where(lumCD => lumCD.lumId.SequenceEqual(packet.SelfID))
  .ForEach(lumCD => {
     lumCD.ledPwr += packet.LedPwr;
     lumCD.batChargePwr += packet.batchrgpwr;
     lumCD.batDischargePwr += packet.battdispwr;
     lumCD.count++;
     }
  );
```

Comment: ya property name was spelling mistake sorry for that

Comment: @NithinShettigar: That "spelling mistake" means one of two things: (1) You're getting compiler errors that you aren't specifying in the question; or (2) The code in the question isn't the code that's causing the problem.  In either case, your question is unanswerable and all anybody here can do is wildly guess.  Please put in at least *some* effort in describing the problem you're facing.  If it's not important enough for you to meaningfully ask, it's probably not going to be important enough for strangers to meaningfully answer.

Comment: Error 105 A local variable named 'lumCD' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'lumCD', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else 
Error                                                                                              104 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I was missing a close bracket which was giving you those compiler errors, edited now.

Comment: I closed bracket after that its not taking 'foreach' loop

Comment: Error 104 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ILS.lumCummulativeData>.this[int]' because it is not a variable(Errror for your first solution).Should i use class instead of struct??

Comment: I think you have more errors in your own code which we cannot help you with unless you post.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using cummulativeDataList[i] instead of cummulativeData.

Also, check whether do you really need the add function. because you want to change it rather than add a new.

```
for (int i=0; i<cummulativeDataList.Count(); i++)
{
    bool lumIdMatched = cummulativeDataList[i]
                        .lumIdCummulativeData
                        .SequenceEqual(packet.SelfID); 

    if (lumIdMatched == true)
    {
        cummulativeDataList[i].ledPwr += packet.LedPwr;
        cummulativeDataList[i].batChargePwr += packet.batchrgpwr;
        cummulativeDataList[i].batDischargePwr += packet.battdispwr;
        cummulativeDataList[i].count++;
        //cummulativeDataList.Add(cummulativeData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 104 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ILS.lumCummulativeData>.this[int]' because it is not a variable